# How to skip Custom attribute from validation in an Nested Action Method Calls WebApi

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2

In an Web api Action controller.Each Action methods are decorated with attribute extending action filter attribute for security validation.

It has nested action method calls. Due to its nested calls the OnActionExecuting is being called multiple times for the validation.

Is it possible to check the OnActionExecuting only once and skip checking only for child action method calls?

```
 public class WebApiController
 {
    [CustomAttribute]
    public IActionResult ActionMethod1()
    {
         WebApiController222 obj = new WebApiController222()
         obj.ActionMethod2(); // Calling to second Action Methods
    }
 }
    
 public class WebApiController222
 {
    
    [CustomAttribute]
    public IActionResult ActionMethod2()
    {
      //source Code
    }
 }
    
    
 // CustomAttribute
 public class CustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
 {  
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context()
    {
      //Some Code
    }
 }
```

I expect that nested api call (ActionMethod2) should skip the OnActionExecuting from being called.

Comment: The code which  you have shared doesn't show calling a child action.

Answer (score 0):

Don't call ActionMethod2 directly. Put the contents of ActionMethod2 into a function (ActionMethod2Internal), and call that from both places.

```
Public class WebApiController
{
  [CustomAttribute]
  public IActionResult ActionMethod1()
  {
     WebApiController222 obj = new WebApiController222()
     return obj.ActionMethod2Internal(); // Calling to second Action Methods
  }
}

public class WebApiController222
{
  [CustomAttribute]
  public IActionResult ActionMethod2()
  {
    return ActionMethod2Internal();
  }
  public IActionResult ActionMethod2Internal()
  {
    //source code
  }
}

// CustomAttribute
public class CustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{  
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context()
  {
    //Some Code
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Robert Thanks for the reply. Actually nested APIs are called with header data (credentials) and its credentials are same that are validating ActionMethod1 and ActionMethod2. I want to validate only once in the main method and skip its validation in the sub methods... Is it possible to do some code to make the nested action method's attribute -> 'Hey Api this has been already checked in the root. so skip validation here' ?

Comment: I think at the end of this investigation i would probably follow the internal method but Is there any other way to bypass the second attribute validation?